Systemd: creating a service unit to run httpd for unprivileged user
I have an unusual scenario where I want an apache service to be run as an unprivileged user, this is listening on a non-root port (8000+). I have it working, but I have some issues with the custom systemd service I created to manage it.
Here is the service unit:
[Unit]
Description=Apache Modperl service for {user}
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User={user}
Group={user}
Environment=LANG=C
PIDFile={Apache pid file, accessible by user}

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd -f {config file}
ExecReload=kill -USR1 $MAINPID

# Send SIGWINCH for graceful stop
KillSignal=SIGWINCH
KillMode=mixed
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Starting/stopping the service works fine, but when reloading, any issues in the config makes the entire process die. I don't want it to die, but instead keep the old process running with the previous config (just like the standard httpd service when you do a reload on a non working config).
For reference, this is in Oracle Linux 8 and here is the standard httpd service unit (root) I used as a template:
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
Wants=httpd-init.service
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target httpd-init.service
Documentation=man:httpd.service(8)

[Service]
Type=notify
Environment=LANG=C

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful
# Send SIGWINCH for graceful stop
KillSignal=SIGWINCH
KillMode=mixed
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I dont know if I should be using type notify instead of forking, but when I try to use notify, starting the service fails with this message in journalctl:
Failed with result 'protocol'.

I don't get any permission issues or other more verbose messages when attempting to use type notify instead.

Taken From: Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files:

forking: This service type is used when the service forks a child process, exiting the parent process almost immediately. This tells systemd that the process is still running even though the parent exited.

vs

notify: This indicates that the service will issue a notification when it has finished starting up. The systemd process will wait for this to happen before proceeding to other units.

Taking a guess at the failure here, but I would look at what's contained in httpd-init.service  You can't notify the system that your service has completed startup as the original Apache service owned by root has already completed.  I believe the user copy also must listen on a different port number than 80Are you stopping that service before starting the user controlled one?  You might also check the syntax of your config file vs. the original.

I was able to figure it out - I needed to use type notify and have the httpd command use -DFOREGROUND for exec (same as default), the key part was that the httpd conf file used needs to load the sytemd module to play nicely with the service unit (before when I tried it it would start but the service would never return). This module is loaded by default conf but I needed to add it. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_systemd.html
